# Transfer ownership of a contract in the constructor

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale, constructor

I'm trying to create a contract, and set its owner at the same time

```
contract ERC721CrowdSale is Ownable { ... }//contract is in the same file and has access to methods


contract CS_Creator is Ownable{
  ERC721CrowdSale _cs;

  function create_crowdsale(string _name, address _wallet, uint256 _token_goal) onlyOwner returns(address){
      address _new_crowdsale = new ERC721CrowdSale(_name,  _wallet,  _token_goal);
      transfer_CS_ownership(_new_crowdsale, _wallet);
      return _new_crowdsale;
  }

  function transfer_CS_ownership (address _new_crowdsale, address _wallet)  internal {
     _cs = ERC721CrowdSale(_new_crowdsale);
    _cs.transferOwnership(_wallet);
  }
}
```

this creates the crowdsale, but in remix i get an error when i try any methods on the crowdsale

`transact to ERC721CrowdSale.(fallback) errored: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I just need a convenient way to transfer the ownership of the crowdsale to the wallet address.  Right now they are all owned by `CS_Creator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the code in remix with the according complements for owner and ERC721CrowdSale and your code worked fine. I only slightly modified your contract so that I would get the value of the current owner of the crowdsale returned by the function create_crowdsale(...).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Ownable {

    address public owner;

    function Ownable() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
}

contract ERC721CrowdSale is Ownable {

    string public name;
    address public wallet;
    uint256 public token_goal;

    function ERC721CrowdSale(string _name, address _wallet, uint256 _token_goal) public {
        name = _name;
        wallet = _wallet;
        token_goal = _token_goal;
    }
    //...

}

contract CS_Creator is Ownable{
  ERC721CrowdSale _cs;

  function create_crowdsale(string _name, address _wallet, uint256 _token_goal) onlyOwner returns(address, address){
      address _new_crowdsale = new ERC721CrowdSale(_name,  _wallet,  _token_goal);
      transfer_CS_ownership(_new_crowdsale, _wallet);
      return (_new_crowdsale, get_CS_ownership(_new_crowdsale));
  }

  function transfer_CS_ownership(address _new_crowdsale, address _wallet)  internal {
      _cs = ERC721CrowdSale(_new_crowdsale);
      _cs.transferOwnership(_wallet);
  }

  function get_CS_ownership(address _crowdsale) public returns(address) {
      return ERC721CrowdSale(_crowdsale).owner();
  }
}
```

As a return value for the crowdsale owner I get the value for the wallet address.

*I could imagine that you actually created a contract ERC721CrowdSale in remix and then were checking there whether the owner address had changed, after deploying CS_Creator. If so: in this case you are creating a new instance of the contract ERC721CrowdSale with the function create_crowdsale(...) which, therefore, is completely independent from the other ERC721CrowdSale contract, you deployed earlyer. The owner address, however, is only changed in the instance, created by the function create_crowdsale(...).*

Hope it helps!

Comment: So everything appears to work for me, until I create the Crowdsale 'at address" and click on any of the functions (with the remix GUI) and i get the error `transact to ERC721CrowdSale.(fallback) errored: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Well, it actually worked on the Rinkeby Test-net, as opposed to the JVM.  The joys of working with new technology.  Spent many hours playing with this code, only to realize it wasn't broken.